# React native problem with installing dependencies when creating a module bridge

Tags: android, module, dependencies, react-native

I'm trying to create a module where I have to install android dependencies, but I'm having a lot of problems.

I do not understand if my fault or problem with the dependencies, installed.

The dependencies I am trying to install are as follows:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:bottomsheetbuilder:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.nbsp:library:1.8'
```

The error that is given to me is such a thing, for example:

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.rubensousa:bottomsheetbuilder:1.6.1
```

Someone can give me a hand.

Comment: Have you tried to run this from Android Studio rather than just command line?

Comment: The fact right from Android studio.